# Why I need to login to Programmers.stackexchange.com again when I already had a session in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, login, software-engineering-se, auto-login

Well, first I thought about asking this in [programmers meta](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/), but decides against it since question about all Stack Exchange networks is allowed here, as per FAQ.

I have already login to Stack Overflow(I use my yahoo email for login), and when I open a new tab and open meta.stackoverflow.com, A pop up saying (something like)

> *Welcome back , you are already logged in, Please refresh.. blabla*

is shown. I just need to refresh to login to meta.stackoverflow.com. All good

But when I try programmers.stackexchange.com, I need to login using my yahoo mail again. I already associated my account there with my Stack Overflow account, so I believe one login in any of the associated sites should save me from login again in other one's.

Why it again ask for login?

Comment: The cookie only lasts so long. If you haven't visited in the site in so long, it eventually forgets who you are. They *are* still separate websites on different domains that can't share the same credentials.

Comment: the duplicated question is not the same as this one. That one is talking abot *registering* for new sites you've never visited before. *This* one is talking about cookies in logins.

Comment: @animuson It's strange that they don't share the same credentials, since when I login to stackoverflow, I can see inbox notifications from my posts in other sites (e.g. AskDifferent), but when I click those notifications, I have to login again.